# What order is null stored in a non clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have some columns in a non clustered index that have values of null in them, one of them for example is expiration date.  There are some values in the column that are null and some supplied.  The way the column is queried is that values that are null or greater than some expiration date are retrieved.  I am using this column in an index and it would be most efficient if I retrieve in descending order with null first.  So I guess I have a two part question:

1. In what order is null stored in a non-clustered index?  Is null first in an ASC index and last in a DESC index?  I had a co-worker who seemed to think null was stored first in both cases.  He also mentioned null was handled differently among version sql server versions.
2. Is there a way to force null first in a non clustered index?  This is kinda dependent on the answer to question one but lets say for arguments sake that indexing is handled like order by where null is first in ASC order.  Is there a way to create a non clustered index that stores values in descending order but with null first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is painfully simple to test. Where is the row with NULL in the following queries?

```
select *
from
(
    select SomeVal = 1 union all
    select 2 union all
    select null
) x
order by x.SomeVal desc


select *
from
(
    select SomeVal = 1 union all
    select 2 union all
    select null
) x
order by x.SomeVal
```

Comment: I had read something that made me think null may not necessarily be stored in the order of an order by but I couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: Or course NULL is part of the sorting order (assuming you have order by on your query). Otherwise NULL would just show up randomly in an otherwise sorted list.